# git branch -vv seems to contradict itself when trying to work out whether by how many commits it is ahead/behind when tracking with remote branches

Tags: git-branch, git-merge

```
$ git status
On branch CurrAsOf18Jan2018
Your branch is up to date with 'remotes/bitbucketFrmWin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**But I know that my bitbucket repo is ahead by a couple of commits Ques:Do I have to always do a git fetch --all so that my local git can be sure - I thought I was tracking my remote repo bitbucketFrmWin - Anyways I do the following .....**

```
$ git fetch --all
Fetching bitbucketFrmWin
From https://bitbucket.org/FreeFries/simplcontactsvcf
   50d1fc6..d79d834  master     -> bitbucketFrmWin/master
```

**Good now my local repo can check against the fetched remotes whether it is ahead/behind**

```
$ git status
On branch CurrAsOf18Jan2018
Your branch is behind 'remotes/bitbucketFrmWin/master' by 5 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
 nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**Okay I am happy with that it is what I thought**

```
$ git branch -vv
* CurrAsOf18Jan2018             50d1fc6 [remotes/bitbucketFrmWin/master: behind 5] Pedantic but done - gitNotes.txt

  bitbucketFrmWin/master        58470cd [CurrAsOf18Jan2018: behind 7] This is really crazy - Spent more than a week - Singleton still gives null pointer inJdbcExample2
```

**Now this is what throws me `[CurrAsOf18Jan2018: behind 7] (see last output line above)` ... It should have said ahead by 5 - after all it is comparing the same remote repo branch. What am I missing in my understanding here ?**

```
$ git merge --no-commit --ff-only d79d834
Updating 50d1fc6..d79d834
Fast-forward
 .gitignore                    |   2 ++
 gitNotesUpgradeInstall.txt    |  38 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 sqliteData/testtestdb.sqlite3 | Bin 278528 -> 0 bytes
 3 files changed, 40 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 gitNotesUpgradeInstall.txt
 delete mode 100644 sqliteData/testtestdb.sqlite3
```

**I go ahead with the git fetch it fast-forward's my local branch - I tell it not to commit - but ignores my request and commits anyways - Why ?**

**Also my bitbucket branch master is actually already ahead at commit d79d834 but "git branch -vv" above does not show that commit sha signature in it's listing despite the fetch - Why ?**

```
$ git status
On branch CurrAsOf18Jan2018
Your branch is up to date with 'remotes/bitbucketFrmWin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**Nevertheless git status knows now that it has caught up with my remote branch above and is happy 
If someone can throw light on the questions posed above as to whether these are bugs or misunderstanding in the git work flow above - I would be grateful. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I go ahead with the git fetch it fast-forward's my local branch - I tell it not to commit - but ignores my request and commits anyways - Why ?

Because there is no commit to be made: it does not make any commit: it just fast-forward your branch HEAD to the remote one.

And `bitbucketFrmWin/master` is a local branch, not remote one!
Its name is poorly chosen, as it matches the one of a remote: `remotes/bitbucketFrmWin/master`.
But being local, it is not surprising it too is behind its remote counterpart (which just got updated with `git fetch bitbucketFrmWin`).

If you want to see your remote as well as local ones, type:

```
git branch -avv
```

You will see a `remotes/bitbucketFrmWin/master` branch as well.

Comment: VonC - (@VonC does not seem to be printed out when I save my Comment) Thanks esp. for that git branch -avv command that is going to be very useful. Though I am perplexed I have not done a checkout -b and created any local branches with those names - at least definitely not explicitly - I would instinctively avoid using names/aliases that I have already set to use on my Remotes.